# Cross product of two infinitesimal bendings

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $M$ be a smooth (embedded or immersed) surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $Z_1,Z_2$ be two vector fields along $M$, thought of as $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued functions, satisfying the following differential equation:

$$\langle XZ_i,Y \rangle + \langle X,YZ_i \rangle =0$$

for all vector fields $X,Y$ on $M$. Here $XZ$ means a derivative with respect to the vector field $X$ of a $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued function $Z$. We will call such $Z_1,Z_2$ *infinitesimal bendings*, since the derivative of a one-parameter family of isometric immersions must satisfy this equation.

**Is it true, that the pointwise cross product $M \ni m\mapsto Z_1(m)\times Z_2(m)$ is also an infinitesimal bending?**

I don't have any particular reason to believe that it might be true, i couldn't prove it by algebraic manipulations, and not trained to produce non-flat surfaces admitting independent infinitesimal deformations to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a rotationally symmetric cylinder, $Z_1$ be a vector field tangent to M generating the isometric translation along the cylinder and $Z_2$ be a vector field also tangent to M generating the isometric  rotation around the cylinder. Then $Z_1\times Z_2$ is a vector field which radially expanding or shrinking the cylinder, which is probably a counter example.